# Example of Sylow $p$-subgroups in finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I would like to understand Sylow $p$-subgroups.

I understand Sylow discovered the converse of Lagrange's Theorem is true for a prime divisor of finite group.

I am trying to understand following example.

$\textbf{Example:}$ Let $G=\Bbb {Z_{12}}$ be group with additive operation.

So $|G|=12=2^23$. Then $G$ has Sylow $2$-subgroup(s) and Sylow $3$-subgroup(s). Ok I know $n_2|3$ and $n_2\equiv 1$ (mod $2$), where $n_2$ the numbers of Sylow $2$-subgroup. So, $n_2=1$ or $n_2=3$.

I can't maintain solution. I have similar question for Sylow $3$-subgroup(s).

In general, I want to know following question answer:

> - Is there a general solution algorithm?

Comment: In any abelian group we have $n_p=1$ for all primes $p$.

Comment: Well, the Sylow Subgroups are all conjugate subgroups, and $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ is abelian. It seems to me there can exist only one. (This fact is noted by Derek Holt as well)

Comment: Ok. $n_p=1$. Because for any sylow $2$-subgroup,say $H$, $gHg^{-1}=H$. In abelian group all subgroups must be normal. Am I correct? How can we find it?

Comment: @1Spectre1 What do you mean be "find it"? In this case we're looking for a group of order $2^2 = 4$, so $\{0,3,6,9\}$ presents itself.

Comment: @Y. Forman,you right. I must be more concentre. The form of subgroups of $\Bbb {Z_n}$ are $\lbrace r\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \ \ | \ \ \ r \mid n \rbrace$